# Decoding Transaction input data in Nethereum

Tags: transactions, abi, nethereum, decoding, .net

I'm using Nethereum and see this example of how to decode the `Input` data of a `Transaction` object. [Nethereum Playground C#](http://playground.nethereum.com/csharp/id/1063)

This looks like it assumes that you have to know which function data you're decoding.  I have the full contract ABI, but I don't know which function was called in this transaction.

Is there a way to decode the `Input` data without already knowing which function it is?  In EthersJs, for example, this is done simply with a `ContractInterface.parseTransaction` method call.

I'm also open to suggestions for other .NET based decoding solutions/libraries.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible but would involve some work. The first 4 bytes of that Input data is the method ID. So if you find a transaction on Etherscan then look at the input data you can find it.
[image: Method id in transaction input data]

This is a hex value and is calculated by taking the method name and its argument types, removing the whitespace then generating a SHA-3 hash of the result.

So you'd first need to write code to generate hashes of the contracts method names using SHA-3, this may not be straightforward as there doesn't seem to be an implementation of it in .NET.

Once you find a way to generate the SHA-3 hashes figuring out the function would be a case of comparing the input data you are using with the generated hashes. When you have confirmed the function you can create an instance of it then call the **decodeInput()** method.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I've done it in Netherium - this decodes a Transaction class to the correct Function class (Generated from Abi):

```
foreach (var type in Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetTypes())
{
    if (type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(FunctionMessage)))
    {
        var abiFunction = ABITypedRegistry.GetFunctionABI(type);

        if (txn.Input.StartsWith($"0x{abiFunction.Sha3Signature}"))
        {
            var m = typeof(FunctionMessageExtensions)
                .GetMethod("DecodeTransactionToFunctionMessage")
                .MakeGenericMethod(type);
            var function = m.Invoke(null, new object[] { txn });
        }
    }
}
```